# ADO RecordSet changing data type when running the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, oledb, adodb

I'm having a weird issue here and I'm hoping someone can help me.

We are using classic asp (big application with lots of legacy code that we still haven't got the chance to update) with sql server 2008.

To connect to SQL, we are using the SQLOLEDB provider with ADODB connections.

I'm running this code

```
    If tblUserFields.State = 1 then tblUserFields.Close

    qryUserFields = "SELECT Language_Code, Field_Section, Field_Group, Field_Id FROM uvw_UserFields_Display WHERE Client_Id=" & Client_Id & " AND Project_Id=" & Project_Id & " AND Language_Code='" & Language_Code & "' AND Field_Section='" & Section & "' ORDER BY Field_Group, Field_Id;"

    tblUserFields.Open qryUserFields, conn,3,3
```

This is run inside a function, I'm calling this function depending on the `Field_Section` value it should return a different list of fields.

Then depending on `RecordCount <> 0` I print the field values on the page or not.

The thing is, the first time it works fine, but the second time (for a different section) it give me recorcount = 0 for some reason **but** if I copy paste the same query in SQL Management Studio it gives me the correct results for both sections.

So I started using this code to debug

```
    Response.Write "<br />" & tblUserFields.RecordCount & "<br />"
    Response.Write "<br />" & tblUserFields.State & "<br />"
    Response.Write "<br />" & tblUserFields.BOF & "<br />"
    Response.Write conn.Provider
    For i = 0 To tblUserFields.Fields.Count -1
        Response.Write "Field Name: " & tblUserFields.Fields(i).Name & "<br>"
        Response.Write "Field Value: " & VarType(tblUserFields(i)) & "<br>"
    Next
```

The first and second time this runs on the page, the results are fine with the correct datatypes.

```
2

1

False
SQLOLEDB.1

Field Name: Language_Code
Field Value: 8
Field Name: Field_Section
Field Value: 8
Field Name: Field_Group
Field Value: 8
Field Name: Field_Id
Field Value: 3
```

And so on, but the third time this same code gets called on the same page it changes all datatypes to objects for some reason.

```
0

1

True
SQLOLEDB.1
Field Name: Language_Code
Field Value: 9
Field Name: Field_Section
Field Value: 9
Field Name: Field_Group
Field Value: 9
Field Name: Field_Id
Field Value: 9
```

Comment: @Lankymart How is that helpful?

Comment: You get `RecordCount = 0` on your second attempt so your query is returning no data why, what should you be debugging? Have you checked the values of `Client_Id`, `Project_Id`, `Language_Code` and `Section` in your `qryUserFields` sql statement on the second run for a different section?

Comment: @Lankymart Of course I have and if you read the full thing I say that when I run the same queries in SQL Management Studio it gives me a number of rows depending on the section, but the third time I run this on the page it gives me RecordCount = 0. But, It's fine I solved it without your help.

Comment: So your outputting `qryUserFields` and using that to run your query in SSMS? I assumed you meant you were just running your query in SSMS and wondering why it worked. Why not provide that information it would help far more then some field debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reason when calling the function

Like this:

```
DisplayUserField("A")
```

It's fine but when calling it like this

```
DisplayUserField("B")
```

For the B section of the page, it was adding a vbCrLf in the background for some reason. When doing a `Response.Write "Section : " & Section & "<br />"` and checked the HTML I saw the carriage return

Now in the function I'm doing this

```
Section = Replace(Section, vbCrLf, "")
```

Before running the query and it is returning the correct results as expected.

Comment: You said you outputted your SQL if you had you would have got something like `AND Field_Section='B

'`. Which is what I asked in your question. At least you found the cause I guess.